# How can I send variables over the internet on QBasic?

Tags: qbasic, qb64

I'm making a little multiplayer retro game in **QBASIC** (QB64). I need to send some integers from one player to the other. Does anyone know how I can do it and who can maybe give me the source code?

Comment: Seems too broad. Unlikely to be ready-made code which does exactly what you want (which itself isn't very clear). There is this: https://www.qb64.org/wiki/TCP/IP_Message_Format

Comment: How can I open a host session?

Comment: When using QBasic inside of DOSBox you can use serial port modem or nullmodem emulation

Answer (score 2):

Exchanging data via tcp/ip with QB64: http://www.qb64.org/wiki/Inter-Program_Data_Sharing_Demo

Answer (score -1):

Another link to swap tcp/ip data:

http://www.qb64.org/wiki/OPENHOST

might work.